# IllegalThreadStateException Error on Simple Chat Application using Socket Programmin, Code bellow

Tags: java, sockets

Client code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOError;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class messages_client
{
    static BufferedReader in;
    static  Scanner sc;
    static PrintWriter out;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try{
            JFrame frame=new JFrame();
            Socket client=new Socket("localhost",59001);
            in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            out=new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
            sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean running=false;
            
            String input=in.readLine();
            System.out.println(input);
            String name=sc.next();
            out.println(name);
            running=true;
    
            Thread send=new Thread(new send());

            Thread recieve=new Thread(new recieve());
            
            if(running == true)
            {
            while(true)
            {
             send.start();
             recieve.start();   
            }
            }

        } catch(IOException e){}

    }
    
    public static class send implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            String message=sc.nextLine();
            out.println(message);
        }

    }

    public static class recieve implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    try {
                        String input=in.readLine();
                        System.out.println(input);
                        
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class messages_server
{
    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static Set<PrintWriter> printwriters=new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try{
        server=new ServerSocket(59001);
        var pool=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        System.out.println("Server is running");
        while(true)
        {
            pool.execute(new ClientHandler(server.accept()));
        }
        } catch(IOException e)
        {
        } finally
        {
            try{
             server.close();
            } catch(IOException e){}
        }
    }

    private static class ClientHandler implements Runnable
    {
        private Socket client;
        private static PrintWriter out;
        private static BufferedReader in;
        private static String message;
        private static String name;

        ClientHandler(Socket client)
        {
            this.client=client;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try{
            out=new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
            in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

            send("Name: ");
            name=in.readLine();
            System.out.println(name);
            out.println("1");
            broadcast(name+" has joined the chat");
            

            while(true)
            {
              message=in.readLine();
              broadcast(name+":"+message);
            }

            } catch(IOException e){}finally
            {
                if(in != null)
                {
                    printwriters.remove(out);
                    broadcast(name+" has left the chat");
                }

                try{
                client.close();
                }catch(IOException e){}
            }
        }

        public void broadcast(String message)
        {
            for(PrintWriter printwriter:printwriters)
            {
                printwriter.println(message);
            }
    
        }
    
        public void send(String message)
        {
            out.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have created this simple Chat Application where multiple users can join a common chat.The Server creates a different thread for each client and continuously recieves and broadcasts data.The client to has two threads: "send" "recieve" which send and recieve data continuosly.

The Server works fine but when I run the client after typing in my name there shows `IllegalThreadStateException`.

Please help and suggest if there is anyway I can improve this code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confused about what `Thread`'s `start()` method does.

In your code:

> ```java
> Thread send = new Thread(new send());
> Thread recieve = new Thread(new recieve());
> ```

You create exactly one thread (`send`) for sending, and exactly one (`recieve` - note you have a typo, it's "receive". English is weird) for receiving.

You then:

> ```java
> while(true)
> {
>   send.start();
>   recieve.start();
> }
> ```

**repeatedly** (while loop) invoke `.start()` on these single threads.

That's not how it works: You can only start a Thread object **once**, ever. If you invoke `.start()` the second time, you get `IllegalThreadStateException`, because the state is 'STARTED' and you can't call `.start()` on such a thread.

What's not quite clear is your intent. Were you intending to continually start threads? Then you'd have to create a new thread object every time and then start it, i.e. move the `Thread send = ...;` code inside the while loop. However, I can't imagine you want that: If you stick that in a `while(true)` the system will create an infinite amount of threads, starts them, and, naturally, crashes very very quickly and very definitely if you try that.

If your intent is simply to keep that one send and one receive thread from continuing to run - there is no need to repeatedly invoke `.start()` or do anything else from the `main` method - your receive and send runnables *already* have loops (they both have a `while(true)` loop of their own).

If you intent is to restart any thread that somehow stopped itself, 'just in case' - that's not how it works. Once a thread ends you can't start it again - you'd have to make a new one. And as discussed before, just making an endless amount of threads is just going to lead to a swift crash. You CAN ask a thread if it is no longer running, and then create a new thread and start the new one, but you shouldn't defensively program.

Let me clarify that, because the term 'defensive programming' is overloaded: You should not write code to deal with situations that are not understood. In this case, the situation is: "I dont quite know how, but lets just imagine the send thread is somehow stopped. I want to restart it if this happens". The reason that kind of defensive programming is bad, is: By definition you don't really know what happened (after all, you have no idea how some state COULD happen, therefore it is likely that you're missing rather crucial understanding about what's going on when the to you impossible situation does evidently occur), so the odds that you're doing the right thing (that 'just restart it' is the right answer to 'huh, weird, that thread stopped and I do not understand why') are low.

Most likely, the situation you can't fathom happening can, in fact, never happen, so you wrote a bunch of code that never ever runs. This leads to the biggest problem of defensive programming: The code is untestable, *and* rarely (often never) runs, which means any bugs in it go completely unnoticed. So you now have useless code that if it ever becomes useful, doesn't work at all.

It is *FAR* better to just hard-crash out with an exception in such impossible cases. At least then, if it does occur, you have a lead on investigating. Only after you understand can you write code that deals with the situation.

Comment: Thank you! Also i am just learning about these concepts